# Is there an iOS "kitchen sink" app with source code available anywhere?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm learning iOS development and would really like to look at an example application that shows most of the default elements in iOS and their implementations. A year or so ago, I worked with a javascript framework (Titanium) that had an example like this but I'm wondering if one exists that is written as a native app in Objective-C.

Comment: There's lots of examples provided by Apple that show many different things in "real life" examples.

Comment: I'm mostly asking because I'd like to have one place to look at things like different animation effects, different types of modals, etc. Sometimes the naming doesn't totally convey what the different types are without looking at a visual example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple's [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project may be what you're after.

> This sample is a catalog exhibiting many views and controls in the UIKit framework, along with their various properties and styles.