# Kitchen sink app for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an iOS “kitchen sink” app with source code available anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941260/is-there-an-ios-kitchen-sink-app-with-source-code-available-anywhere)

I am looking for an iOS equivalent to the Titanium app named Kitchen Sink. Does anyone know if it exists? I saw Kitchen Sink and believe it is a terrific learning tool. An equivalent app on iOS would be invaluable......

I have searched this site and found suggestions, but they are all merely HTML pages. I am looking for a real, interactive app which allows the user the interact with each type of control.

Comment: If you read the thread you are referring to, you would have realized this is precisely what I referred to in my post. This is NOT the same question.

Comment: I did read it, and your question is identIcal. There is even an answer which sounds like what you are looking for. In what way is your question different?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I did not see the response suggesting Apple's UICatalog sample project. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ios Boilerplate](http://iosboilerplate.com/)

According to their site, it is:

- a base template for iOS apps
- it is intended to provide a base of code to start
- It is not intended to be a framework
- It is intended to be modified and extended by the developer to fit their needs
- It includes solid third-party libraries if needed to not reinvent the wheel."

Also: "iOS Boilerplate includes helper classes and examples about the following topics:"

- HTTP requests and an image cache (both in-memory and disk-based)
- UITableViews and UITableViewCells: fast scrolling, async images, pull-down-to-refresh, swipeable cells
- A built-in browser so your users don't leave your application when they browse to a certain URL
- Maps and locations: directions between two points, autocomplete a location, etc."

Is that what you are looking for?